# Google App script extracting data from website

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-apps, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

So I am writing a script which look at [review done on google+ pages](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AlecDoranTwyford/reviews)
and updates a google spreadsheet.

I have found out that the line in the html which holds this value is

```
<span class="A7a">103</span>
```

I just need to make it possible for me to extract from the page with just knowing the URL and that html code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.website.com/");
```

To fetch the html of the page. Then use something like

```
var cut = response.substring( str.indexOf( "<span class="A7a">" ), response.length);
var value = cut.substring(0, cut.indexOf("</span>"));
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the previous answer but there are some omissions

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var str = response.getContentText();
var balise = '<span class="A7a">'
var cut = str.substring(str.indexOf( balise ), response.length);
var value = cut.substring(balise.length, cut.indexOf("</span>"));
```